# MSSQL: How to SELF JOIN on two columns with OR Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below tables also shared a script to generate data and related schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #User
(
  Id INT,
  Name NVARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #User VALUES (1, 'James')
INSERT INTO #User VALUES (2, 'Luke')
INSERT INTO #User VALUES (3, 'Miranda')
INSERT INTO #User VALUES (4, 'Lisa')

CREATE TABLE #Task
(
  Id INT,
  Name NVARCHAR(200),
  Assignee INT,
  Evaluator INT
)

INSERT INTO #Task VALUES (1, 'Test 1', 1, 3)
INSERT INTO #Task VALUES (2, 'Test 2', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO #Task VALUES (3, 'Test 3', 0, 0)
INSERT INTO #Task VALUES (4, 'Test 4', 1, 4)
```

What I have tried:

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM #Task T
JOIN #User U ON T.Assignee = @UserId OR T.Evaluator = @UserId
```

---

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 1;
SELECT * 
FROM #Task T
JOIN #User U ON T.Assignee = @UserId AND T.Evaluator = @UserId
```

Expected output:

```
Id  Name    Assignee    Evaluator   Id    Name    EvalName 
1   Test 1     1           3         1    James    Miranda
2   Test 2     0           1         1    NULL     James
4   Test 4     1           4         1    James    Lisa
```

EDIT:

**I have changed some data in the existing question also specified in the output, which was missed at the time of posting question.**

In the updated result I just need evaluator name in case evaluator available otherwise null or empty string

Comment: I have voted to close this question as unclear. There is no actual question in the "question" nor is there a description of the goal. After answering, the requirements were changed, but with no additional details, making this only more unclear.

Comment: Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric thanks for the pointing it out. Can you tell me what is missing in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the future, if you've got an answer that returns your expected result, but later you realise that the problem is more complicated than you originally described, you'd better ask another question and include extra details and different expected result in the new question.

---

In the current state of the question with expected result showing names for both `Assignee` and `Evaluator`, it could be achieved with the following query.

Get the rows we need from the `Task` table using filter in the `WHERE`.
Use two left joins to lookup names from the `User` table twice - once for Assignees, second time for Evaluators. We need left join here, because in some rows the `ID` is 0.

**Query**

```
DECLARE @UserId INT = 1;
SELECT
    T.ID
    ,T.Name
    ,T.Assignee
    ,T.Evaluator
    ,@UserId AS ID
    ,Assignees.Name AS AssigneeName
    ,Evaluators.Name AS EvaluatorName
FROM
    #Task T
    LEFT JOIN #User AS Assignees ON Assignees.ID = T.Assignee
    LEFT JOIN #User AS Evaluators ON Evaluators.ID = T.Evaluator
WHERE
    T.Assignee = @UserId OR T.Evaluator = @UserId
ORDER BY
    T.ID
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+----+--------------+---------------+
| ID |  Name  | Assignee | Evaluator | ID | AssigneeName | EvaluatorName |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 | Test 1 |        1 |         3 |  1 | James        | Miranda       |
|  2 | Test 2 |        0 |         1 |  1 | NULL         | James         |
|  4 | Test 4 |        1 |         4 |  1 | James        | Lisa          |
+----+--------+----------+-----------+----+--------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable needs to be referenced in the `WHERE`. Create the relationship between the 2 tables in the `ON`. Your attempt makes a `CROSS JOIN` between the Task table and any rows that have a value of `1` for either `Assignee` or `Evaluator` in the User table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Task T
     JOIN #User U ON T.Assignee = U.ID OR T.Evaluator = U.ID
WHERE U.Id = @UserId;
```

Comment: Hi @larnu This working as expected, one more condition which need to handle

Comment: Then that should have been in your original "question", @PrashantPimpale ; don't move the goal posts *after* you have received answers.

Comment: I missed it completely, pardon!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale there isn't actually a question there to answer. You've just changed the expected results and invalided my answer...

Comment: will specify on the question that

Comment: It does not specify that you answered wrong but I know some sort of info. was missing from my end which I have included that it

Comment: is the expected output achievable? I mean you can guide me for the same..

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*, COALESCE(UA.Id, UE.Id) AS ID, UA.Name AS Name, UE.Name AS EvalName
FROM   #Task AS t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #User AS UA ON t.Assignee = UA.Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #User AS UE ON t.Evaluator = UE.Id
WHERE  UA.Id IS NOT NULL OR UE.Id IS NOT NULL
```